# Navigate to a different page in HTML through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that changes a mainImage to reflect one of the three other images I have on the page when one of them are clicked. I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks on mainImage, it will take it to the page associated with the image shown on mainImage at the time clicked. The image changing functions are working, although I doubt they are very well written. I will include them just in case it could be affecting something else.

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var featureOne = document.getElementById("featureOne");
  featureOne.addEventListener("click", mainToOne, false);
  var featureTwo = document.getElementById("featureTwo");
  featureTwo.addEventListener("click", mainToTwo, false);
  var featureThree = document.getElementById("featureThree");
  featureThree.addEventListener("click", mainToThree, false);
  var mainClick = document.getElementById("mainFeature");
  mainClick.addEventListener("click", mainClick, false);
};

function mainClick() {
  var image = document.getElementById("mainFeature");
  var imgSource = image.src;
  if(imgSource === "feature1.jpg") {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  }
  else if(imgSource === "feature2.jpg") {
    window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com";
  }
  else if(imgSource === "feature3.jpg") {
    window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
  }
}

function mainToOne() {
  var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainFeature");
  mainImage.src = "feature1.jpg";
}

function mainToTwo() {
  var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainFeature");
  mainImage.src = "feature2.jpg";
}

function mainToThree() {
  var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainFeature");
  mainImage.src = "feature3.jpg";
}
```

```html
<img id="mainFeature" src="feature1.jpg"><br>
<img id="featureOne" src="feature1.jpg">
<img id="featureTwo" src="feature2.jpg">
<img id="featureThree" src="feature3.jpg">
```

I also tried placing the images inside  and having the javascript return a string with the address in the href property.

```html
<a href = "javascript:function();"><img></a>
```

Was this more on track to a viable answer?

Comment: What was your question, exactly?

Comment: If you just want when the image is clicked that the user is redirected to a different page why not just use normal html and put the image within a `<a href="somepage.html"><img src="aImg.jpg"/></a>` like so?

Comment: @Parody: Because there are different pages to go to depending on which feature image was clicked earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

- You are using the variable `mainClick` in the `init` function, so that will shadow the function `mainClick` that you are trying to bind to the event.
- When you get the source of the image, you will get the complete URL to the image, not just the image name that you assigned to the source, so the comparisons will fail.

You don't need to get the image source if you plan ahead a bit. The information that you want was already available at an earlier stage. Instead of just setting the image source, you can also store the index of the image in a variable. That way you don't have to compare the image name against a bunch of strings to try to determine which image was clicked.

The code can be refactored to be a bit less repetetive. You can use arrays for the image names and the links.

```
window.onload = init;

function listen(id, ev, handler) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(ev, handler, false);
}

function init() {
  listen("featureOne", "click", mainToOne);
  listen("featureTwo", "click", mainToTwo);
  listen("featureThree", "click", mainToThree);
  listen("mainFeature", "click", mainClick);
};

var currentMain = 0;
var images = [
  "feature1.jpg",
  "feature2.jpg",
  "feature3.jpg"
];
var links = [
  "http://www.google.com",
  "http://www.facebook.com",
  "http://www.bing.com"
];

function mainClick() {
  window.location.href = links[currentMain];
}

function setMain(index) {
  currentMain = index;
  document.getElementById("mainFeature").src = images[index];
}

function mainToOne() {
  setMain(0);
}

function mainToTwo() {
  setMain(1);
}

function mainToThree() {
  setMain(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly and taught me a few things about neat code as well :D